# Mono for Android - SensorType.RotationVector missing

Tags: c#, mono, xamarin.android, android-sensors

According to the [documentation](http://docs.mono-android.net/?link=T%3aAndroid.Hardware.SensorType), the SensorType enum includes a RotationVector value. Which looks like it will do what I want it to. However when I try to use it in my code it tells me **'Android.Hardware.SensorType' does not contain a definition for 'RotationVector'**

Any suggestions as to where this is and how I enable it? I am using Mono for Android v4.2.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[RotationVector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html#TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR) wasn't added until API level 9 (Android v2.3).

If you update your app to target v2.3 you will get access to that value in the enumeration.

Comment: yep, just discovered that on my own. Thanks though